# Select parent of parent when is not null in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

I have these rows in the specific parent child table:

```
Id - parentId
1  - null
2  - null
3  - 2
4  - 2
5  - 4
6  - 1
```

Indeed for example i want to enter 3 and get 2, enter 5 and get 2, and enter 6 and get 1, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need a hierarchical query (`connect by ...`) Something like this:

```
with
  tbl (id, parentid) as (
    select 1, null from dual union all
    select 2, null from dual union all
    select 3, 2    from dual union all
    select 4, 2    from dual union all
    select 5, 4    from dual union all
    select 6, 1    from dual
  )
select  id
from    tbl
where   connect_by_isleaf = 1
start   with id = 5
connect by   id = prior parentid
;

   ID
-----
    2
```

"In real life" you would have a table `tbl` with columns `id` and `parentid` (I simulated that in the `with` clause, but that is just for convenience; remove it first.) And you wouldn't hard-code the starting node; you would likely use a bind variable in the `start with` clause.

The key here is the `where` clause, using the `connect_by_isleaf` pseudocolumn.

Comment: thank you very much i really appreciated it. its work! one more question how can i set one random parent and get all the sub children?(reverse mode)
for example set 2 get=> 3,4,5 or set 4  get=> 5